# Java file deletion fails

Tags: java, file, io, delete-file

I need to delete files from within a java program and have written this code. It fails to delete the file and I can't figure why. The File is not in use and not write protected.

```
public static void delfile(String filetodel) {
    try {
        File file = new File("filetodel");

        if (file.delete()) {
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Delete operation is failed." + filetodel);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may have to remove the quotes there `new File("filetodel")` as you don't use the parameter

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: Consider to use the new NIO.2 File API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to delete the file, there is no need for loading it.

`java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(filetodel);` (where filetodel contains the path to the file)

Returns true if the file was deleted, so you can even put it in your if-clause.

Answer (score 7):

I guess the issue is this:

```
File file = new File("filetodel");
```

This should possibly be (inferred from the parameter *filetodel* passed in the method):

```
File file = new File(filetodel);
```

Everything else seems fine, and is working on my machine.

Comment: hi you are assuming the file will be in the present working dir or the same folder of the java file which is being executed. what if it is somewhere else in system? just a thought!

Comment: @VardhanDG. I'm only assuming that OP is passing the correct path to the file in the method, denoted by `filetodel`.

Comment: it is always good when deleting to give hard coded paths just my opinion

Comment: @VardhanDG. Well, I don't know, and this actually is irrelevant to the question, how OP is passing the path in his method.

Answer (score 0):

hey buddy you should use a path as parameter in delete
static void delete(Path path)
Deletes a file.
static boolean  deleteIfExists(Path path)
Deletes a file if it exists.

search here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

so in your case

```
File file = new File("c://user//filetodel");

file.delete();
```

or use getAbsolutePath(filename) and use it in file path

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to delete file.

```
    public class deletef
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
     {  
    try{

        File file = new File("/home/rahul/Downloads/ou.txt");

        if(file.delete()){
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

   }
}
```

your code is also right but **you have to put extension also in your file**

```
File file = new File("filetodel");
```

here **add extension also of file other wise your code will not delete file**